# How to change the property of snackbar to show from top to bottom in android support design library

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar

I recently came to know about the support design library for android with build version 22.2.0. In that I am very much impressed with most of the custom views which is easy to use. But whereas Customization of those as concern I am completely stuck up with the solutions. In that one of the major portion I am completely struggling is **SnackBar**.

I am using following code to display **SnackBar** in my **Activity**:

```
Snackbar.make (view,"Success",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
```

**Gradle Build library:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Everything works awesome but what i need is to show snackbar from top to bottom instead of default bottom to top property. Please anyone kindly help with your solutions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation :

> Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation. **They show a
>   brief message at the bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left on
>   larger devices.** Snackbars appear above all other elements on screen
>   and only one can be displayed at a time.

I can't have a look to the Snackbar source code now, but maybe you can try to extend the Snackbar class and override the *show()* method or another one to fit your needs.

Comment: showView() is final and most methods are final and/or private.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the layout gravity of the views, add new animations for slide-up/down.

check my answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333521/1031297