# SnackBar from top. Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-snackbar

I wanted to provide the `SnackBar` animation from top, instead of the regular behavior that displays the `SnackBar` from bottom. Is this easily hackable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. The documentation states that

> They show a brief message at the **bottom** of the screen on mobile and
>   lower left on larger devices. Snackbars appear above all other
>   elements on screen and only one can be displayed at a time.

You could use a third part library, like [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) for instance

Answer (score 5):

it is possible.
check this library made by me https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

basically you add 2 new animations for sliding from top, and change the gravity of the layout. That's all :)

Later Edit: there's a bug going on.... . if anyone wants to spend some time into fixing it we'd all appreciate it :)

Comment: Unfortunately your library suffers from a huge bug, in which the TSnackBar will only appear once if you change activity/fragment, so unfortunately it's unusable in production.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa huge..like let's say 100 meters tall ? or huge like 150kg ? .... didn't had time to fix it, but you're welcome to make a PR.

Comment: I'm trying to fix it, but I cannot find the cause, if you know where it is just explain and i'll try to look at it in my spare time, thanks !

Comment: open source doesn't ask for more.. we're all doing this in our spare time. but if you "need" this library, and you found a solution it would be great to share it with the rest.

Comment: No, I just added a simple view to the top of another, empty layout. No animations, no single support. My client won't pay me to investigate it further :<

Comment: i have an issue using the provided library every time i change between fragments and i dismiss it the body of snackbar is dismissing first and after split of  a second the shadow of snackbar causing a bad user experience..

Comment: I know. I need some time to fix that ugly bug. If someone manages to do it before me, please kindly make a push req.

Comment: @OWADVL What bug does it have?
I did not face any issue while using this lib. But my use case was very small one. I would like to know what issue other people are talking about and possibly fix it if I can. So, can you please tell me what the issue is and how to reproduce that issue?

Comment: its returning a exception that is "Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable', referenced from method com.androidadvance.topsnackbar.TSnackbar.getBitmap"

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa I solved that by using a singleton class and create a new snackbar everytime. Works fine for me now. I can share the code if anyone's interested.

Comment: Yep, you should create your own answer and get the karma upvotes :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 CoordinatorLayout   coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
   View view = snackbar.getView();
   CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
      snackbar.show();
```

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work for over 48 straight hours. I know it is discouraged to do this, but as someone exhausted from trying everything I found before, thank you, thank you very much. Your solution was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: It can move the view to top but animation is still from bottom to up, right?

Comment: it crashes on android 6

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This solution renders Snackbar on top, but animation is from bottom.

It is possible, at least with [Android Material](https://material.io/develop/android/) library and a little trick.
You can bind snackbar to a view that renders on top position like this:

On `activity_main.xml`:

```
<!-- rest of the components here -->

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"/>
```

On `MainActivity.kt`:

```
val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
    findViewById(R.id.top_coordinator),
    "Hello World",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
)

snackbar.show()
```